# Post a form and refresh in a div

Tags: jquery, html, post

I load a PHP file with `.load()` into a div called `#content`

I want to do a post but how can I let jQuery know it only needs to refresh the `#content` div rather than the entire page?

Searched the web about Ajax posts and jQuery posts and tried many things but nothing worked..

**JS:**

```
$("#donateForm").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url:'donate.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data:'any=data&more=data',
        success:function(data){
           $('#content').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

On my donate page:

```
<form id="donateForm">
<p><button id="MyButton">Do it</button></p>
</form>
```

But in my address bar I'm getting an question mark like it's a GET method instead of a POST?

Comment: 'tried allot of thing. Nothing worked..' Such as....?

Comment: Im sorry, here is an example.

See updated first post!

Comment: @Yooouuri, you seem to have a habit of asking questions and not marking any of the answers. When you get an answer you, you should mark it off by clicking the check mark on the left of the answer. Go back through your previous questions.

Answer (score 2):

google is your friend.

anyways:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'ths/url/to/your.php',
    type: 'post',
    data:'any=data&more=data',
    success:function(data){
       $('#yourDivID').html(data);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your submit event is trying to bind to `#donateForm` which seems not to exist at the time the bind is made because as you said, it is content that is later dynamically loaded into the `#content` div using `load()`.

You need to use event delegation, try this:

```
$("#content").on("submit", "#donateForm", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url:'donate.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data:'any=data&more=data',
        success:function(data){
           $('#content').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

This says "look for a submit within `#content`, then check that it is `#donateForm` that triggered the submit event."

If you don't use delegation and you are trying to bind to an element that doesn't (yet) exist, it will not work.